# How do I remove the circular container for my jQuery Mobile nav icons?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

**How to remove the circular container around my custom icons?**

I'm using jQuery Mobile and I have already removed the background with the `ui-nodisc-icon` class. But my icons are still being cropped into a circle. They are, for the most part, square icons.

[image]

Comment: Use inspect element on the element and show us its css properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the border-radius css property to 0px; add this line to your css.

```
.ui-nodisc-icon{
    border-radius:0px !important
}
```